# A Downloaded Codeigniter site from FTP not working on XAMPP or WAMP localhost

Tags: codeigniter, xampp, wamp

my very first post to the forum.. Only due to the fact I've just started a new Job in development and I've spent over xmas trying to get this to work! The job requires me to carry on with JQuery & PHP with the ongoing project - but done offline(localhost) in wamp or xammp and not 'live' as you call it, its already an 8 months project so ideally this does need to be setup like this as I've just started.

I've looked everywhere, I've tried playing around plenty with the .htaccess file, config, checked database, checked routes. Everything on stack overflow.

Now, when they let me try this on my personal server (1and1) to see if it all worked when I copied there ftp files to mine - IT WORKED! But in XAMPP or WAMP it doesn't, for starters it said missing 'MY_CONTROLLER' class which I fixed, it does seem to work when I changed

How come this is working on 1and1 but not on localhost(XAMPP/WAMP) etc?

Please be aware, I have looked everywhere for a solution. All I can think is PHP versions & tweaks on the server installation? Any help would be great, I've been tempting to post for the last week!

UPDATE: I forgot to mention, I followed a tip on here regarding the .htaccess file, it got me to land on the home.php but it wasnt displaying any views, so I changed the       < ? tags to       < ? php           and just gave me a lot of errors, before that all it was displaying its just plain HTML and no CSS with load->view-> everywhere

Comment: Your home environment (WAMPServer/XAMPP) will not mimic your live environment if you are putting the site in a sub folder of the DocumentRoot folder. So setup a Virtual Host and put the site in that. [See how to here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried documentroot in httpd.conf, even in xampp and wamp I've moved all the file structure in the root www/ or htdocs/ and still no luck.. Just keeps appearing with pure html (plain text with view-> etc) -- I have tried AMPPS and did the same thing and this worked which made my day! But I still need to know the problem which is causing this to happen in XAMPP and WAMP for future purposes I guess..

Comment: When you changed to `<?php` WHAT errors did it give. It sounds like you have code written for an old version of PHP and you are running a fairly new version of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED - I created a virtual host and set up windows hosts with the same domain e.g 127.0.0.1, basically what Riggs said so if anyone else is having trouble see his link - and read carefully! Should of put this sooner so sorry - I'm new